# Prevent to continue the scroll of a div when the scrollbar has reached 95%

Tags: javascript

How to prevent to continue the scroll of a div when the scrollbar has reached 95% of the total scroll?

Comment: I do not know how to know the percentage of the scroll, I do not know which event to use, I do not know how to block the scroll. So why I asked you a hint? :P

Comment: Are you talking about the entire body of the page, or a separate div that is sectioned off and has its own inline scrollbar?

Comment: A separate div that is sectioned off and has its own inline scrollbar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not demonstrated a failed example, I can give you a 95% completed solution.

```
(function (w, d) {
    w.scroll(function () {
        var scrollBottom = 95 * (w.scrollTop() + w.height()) / d.height();

        if (scrollBottom > 95) {
            w.scrollTop(  /* what you put here is my exercise for you */  )
        }
    });
}($(window), $(document));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, a little clarification, the scroll function is called after the div is scrolled? Instead of reporting the level of scroll to 95% as you have shown, can I put a return false; to stop the scroll just over 95%?

Comment: You can't stop someone from scrolling by returning false. When scroll() is fired, the user has already scrolled. That's why you can only "scroll back up" - making it look like you can't scroll down - the way my code is set up for you.